# python SQLITE database connection wrapper

Tags: python, sqlite, database-connection

I have the following setting:

- a restricted system that contains SQLite database and is able to use python.
- a usual PC-system.

My aim is to write an application (preferable JAVA) for the PC-system to connect to the SQLite databse on the remote System to read, alter, etc. tables. Unfortunaetly I'm not able to install a Webserver on the remote system because system restrictions deny this intention. So i have been asking myself if it is possible to connect to the database anyway?! I thought of something like a Python connection wrapper, that redirects all database calls. Hope someone can give me a hint for solving this problem.

Comment: So these restrictions forbid you to install a web server, but do not forbid you to install another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is not "db server" but "db file". You can't connect remotly to it because it is not server (you had to write own server). You can copy file with data to another computer and use it but you get two seperated databases. If you can share (in network) folder with that file you can use it on all computers - but there can be problem with concurent writing. SQLite is not designed to work with many users at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! That is a pity. Unfortunately i cannot install any other database like e.g. mySQL. But then i will try to solve this by using an XML-file instead of the database.

Comment: As I sad, SQLite is not server (like MySQL or Postgres), it is file like XML or JPG. You need program to open it and make changes. Every program to work with SQLite-file have to load/open it like image editor open/load JPG. If you can find SQLite file with your data you can copy it to another computer and use it with other program. With XML file you will have the same situation.

Comment: Btw: Firefox use SQLite-file (in place of XML) to save all informations. There is even Firefox extension to work with SQLite-file [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) but always SQLite-file have to be on your local computer or on drive (in local network) accessible from your computer.